# Running remote commands(SSH) in cypress

Tags: cypress

We have few Commands to run on remote machines before we execute our Cypress Test.

Example:

Login on website on a different server using cypress script
Start a server on a different machine
From UI , verify that the server is started using Cypress.

How can we handle SSH using cypress? Any command APIs that supports this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The only command that I can think of is `cy.exec()`, but I am not sure ssh would work when using this command.